# SqlCeCommand does NOT support subqueries?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

yesterday I wanted to create a sql query ( using system.data.sqlce ) which return values from diff tables on mobile devices.

My scenario is as follows:
- sql table: Xtable (fields: name : is string, mat :  is string, state : is int value);
- XTable contains 100 records
my sql statement is:

```
SELECT name, (SELECT count(*) from Xtable where state=0) as Marked, count(*) as Total
FROM XTable
GROUP BY name
```

result: 0 rows, because i have error with second SELECT.

IF I execute following sql statement:

```
SELECT name, count(*) as Total FROM XTable GROUP BY name
result : > 0 rows.
```

Sqlcecommand not support multiselect query?
how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Compact does not support this type of subquery.  See [this MSDN Forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/df8c5ea3-13b6-4925-8177-068b75c16ee4) for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

If you can give error details then it would be easy to help you.

```
(SELECT count() from Xtable where state=0)
```

No argument in count()

```
(SELECT count(*) from Xtable where state=0)
```

**Edit**

In your edit you have ***** as argument in **count**. It was missing originally, is it correct.